# Amazon States Language: Java Library

Tags: amazon-web-services, orchestration

https://states-language.net/spec.html

Is there an API/library which I can use to process states as per this standard. I understand AWS resources are available; is there anything independent of AWS and in the java library that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no Java implementation/bindings outside AWS.

Netflix [Conductor blog](http://techblog.netflix.com/2016/12/netflix-conductor-microservices.html) states:

> Recently announced AWS Step Functions added some of the features we were looking for in an orchestration engine. There is a potential for Conductor to adopt the *states language* to define workflows.

So - since their *decider* component is a Java service - maybe that could become a Java implementation someday.

https://github.com/totherik/step is based on **nodejs** and focused on *openwhisk* compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

There is complete lightweight microservice platform (probably fastest on the market) called light4j eventuate. One of subproject is https://github.com/networknt/light-workflow-4j which implements Amazon States Language completely.